# JPA+EJB not managed entity in websocket communication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

1. Browser and server connected with websocket
2. After connected, browser will send data, and handled in server by method 'firstMessage'. This method will store *Player* entity to variable named 'player' and change its data (it work fine, the database is change )
3. Next, the browser send data again handled in server by method 'secondMessage'. It change the Player entity data that already stored before. the data is change, but the problem is the database not changing

   ```
   @Singleton
   @Startup
   public class Engine {

   @Inject DaoPlayer daoPlayer;
   Player player;    

   public void firstMessage(clientId){
       player = daoPlayer.findById(clientId);
       player.coin = 3;
   }

   public void secondMessage(){
       player.coin = 999;
   ```

   }

**Problem :**

Change in Player entity inside method 'secondMessage' not updating the database

**What i try so far :**

- I already check class Engine, DaoPlayer and Player is the same
  instance (by generating random number when they created)
- i do this in secondMessage and it work fine. but i dont want to this.

  ```
  public void secondMessage(){
      player.coin = 999;
      daoPlayer.getEntityManager().merge(player);
  ```

  }

  i expecting

  player.coin = 999; should be enough to update the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

You need to code `secondMessage` as

```
public void secondMessage() {
    player.coin = 999;
    player = daoPlayer.merge(player);
}
```

Your first method works because the `player` object remains part of the current persistence context until the transaction is completed (possibly when the method returns).

The second method cannot work because the `player` is no longer a part of any persistence context. The `merge` operation merges it back into a persistence context, possibly returning a different instance if it had been loaded earlier in your call chain.

Comment: thank you sir, but i still bothered, can you please give a little clue why is work fine on 'firstMessage' but not work in 'secondMessage' ?